# React App Using TensorFlow Detects Wrong Object

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am following a tutorial on [Object Detection](https://github.com/hugozanini/TFJS-object-detection) with Javascript.

Here's a code snippet that bothers me right now:

```
let classesDir = {
    1: {
        name: 'Kangaroo',
        id: 1,
    },
    2: {
        name: 'Other',
        id: 2,
    }
}
```

So far, the app should detect object **Kangaroo** or it'll detect other objects as **Other**. Interesting thing is whatever object I try to detect using device camera, it detects that as **Kangaroo**. Right now, it uses the following model:

```
const model = await loadGraphModel("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hugozanini/TFJS-object-detection/master/models/kangaroo-detector/model.json");
```

When I tried instead to use the following model that's bit different:

```
const model = await loadGraphModel("https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2/model.json");
```

it throws an exception:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arraySync')
```

Here's the code snippet where the exception starts in the **index.js** file:

```
//Getting predictions
const boxes = predictions[4].arraySync(); //Exception here
const scores = predictions[5].arraySync();
const classes = predictions[6].dataSync();
```

For the above scenario, I changed the object name to something else to detect but every time, it detects every object as the same one even that's different. Is there anything that requires to do with the model, I am not sure?

Comment: Link of previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433940/library-to-detect-specific-object

Comment: Please avoid storytelling and other stuff irrelevant to the issue; regarding your "Update 1", please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO (edited out).